# How can I run node-schedule script on a new date defined inside script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, job-scheduling

Code

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var date = new Date();
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 2);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function (fire) {
    console.log(fire);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 10)
});
```

I want to run the script again and again with a new date. This date can be any date, not only + 10 minutes

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? I cannot seem to understand the expected result here.